# Insertar en BD con Oracle Data Acces en C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Estoy tratando de insertar en una tabla de Oracle con este código, y me arroja este mensaje de error:

> "El valor no está dentro del intervalo esperado."

He tratado de diferentes maneras y siempre me arroja el mismo error.

```
oc.Open();

OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter();



OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROW_ID, CREATED, STATUS) " +
   "VALUES (:pROW_ID, :pCREATED, :pSTATUS", oc);


OracleParameter ROW_ID = new OracleParameter("pROW_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15, "ROW_ID");
OracleParameter CREATED = new OracleParameter("pCREATED", OracleDbType.Date, 30, "CREATED");
OracleParameter STATUS = new OracleParameter("pASIGNADO", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15, "STATUS");
ROW_ID.Value = BDOracleObtenerRowIDBackOffice();

ROW_ID.Value = = "146721030020001";
CREATED.Value = "SYSDATE";
STATUS.Value = "ON_HOLD";

cmd.Parameters.Add("pROW_ID", ROW_ID);  //<-- Here throws exception
cmd.Parameters.Add("pCREATED", CREATED);
cmd.Parameters.Add("pSTATUS", STATUS);

oda.InsertCommand = cmd;
```

> Traza: en Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter..ctor(String parameterName, Object obj) en Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection.Add(String name, Object val) en TestCore.MyClass.functionInsert(String param) en C:\Users\user_01\source\repos\file.cs:línea 2945

Comment: El id qué tipo de dato es ?

Comment: Saludos ZythGera, ¿podrías colocar la definición de tu tabla?

Comment: Si ya defines el nombre del parametro cuando instancias `OracleParameter` porque en el `Add()` lo vuelves a indicar ? no alcanza con `cmd.Parameters.Add(ROW_ID); `

Comment: imagino que aqui `ROW_ID.Value = = "146721030020001";` el tenes dos veces el  `=` no este afectando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente está resulto, el código correcto es el siguiente:

```
using (oc)
{
    oc.Open();


    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO myTable (ROW_ID, CREATED, STATUS) " +
      "VALUES (:pROW_ID, SYSDATE, :pSTATUS)", oc);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("pROW_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "146721030020001", ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pSTATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "ON_HOLD", ParameterDirection.Input);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No creo que puedas indicarle una funcion en el parametro quizas debas asignar la fecha usando

```
CREATED.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

O en caso concrerio indicarlo en la query

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROW_ID, CREATED, STATUS) 
                 VALUES (:pROW_ID, SYSDATE, :pSTATUS"
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, oc);
```

lo asignas directo sin enviar el parametro

Comment: La respuesta de arriba funcionó, enviando 'SYSDATE' en la query, se inserta la fecha del servidor. En cualquier caso, no podía utilizar DateTime.Now, ya que la fecha del servidor de base de datos es diferente y es la que necesito.

Comment: ok pero mi respuesta tambien incluia definir el sysdate en el query directamente

Comment: Tienes razón. Pero, cuando publiqué la pregunta el código no llegaba hasta ahí, fallaba cuando intentaba agregar el parámetro ROW_ID. De Igual forma, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!